# How to group by embedded values and set a name to it with total count in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql-aggregation

My Collection :
[image: Collection]

Sample Collection Json Structure:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f30df2ca032ecb2d14568bf"), 
    "value" : {
        "busId" : 100.0, 
        "status" : {
            "code" : {
                "id" : 1.0, 
                "key" : "2100", 
                "value" : "Complete"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Goal is to get the count of status for approve and reject for individual busID.

```
db.suraj_coll.aggregate([
    {"$group" : {_id:{busId:"$value.busId",status:"$value.status.code.value"}, count:{$sum:1}}}
])
```

The above query returns the output
(Sample Output):

```
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "busId" : 200.0, 
        "status" : "Cancel"
    }, 
    "count" : 2.0
}
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "busId" : 100.0, 
        "status" : "Accept"
    }, 
    "count" : 1.0
}
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "busId" : 100.0, 
        "status" : "Complete"
    }, 
    "count" : 2.0
}
```

But I would like to put a condition that, whenever it finds the value $in(Complete,Accept), It changes the value to Approved and makes the count 3.
I think it can be done using the $cond (aggregation), but finding it difficult to change the name as well,To be more specify , I would like to have the output as :

```
 { 
        "_id" : {
            "busId" : 200.0, 
            "status" : "Rejected"
        }, 
        "count" : 2.0
    }
    { 
        "_id" : {
            "busId" : 100.0, 
            "status" : "Approved"
        }, 
        "count" : 3
    }
```

So basically whenever it finds Accept/Complete, it increments the value / sum the counts and store against a name Approved. and for cancel changes the value to Rejected.

Any advice/solution will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's great. What you need to do is, just add another field to identify whether its approved or not before grouping, It will make you much easier.

```
{
    $addFields: {
      "value.available": {
        $cond: [
          {
            $in: [
              "$value.status.code.value",
              [
                "Accept",
                "Complete"
              ]
            ]
          },
          "Approved",
          "Rejected"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pdHhpLy29xT)

Comment: Wow.. That works seamlessly ..Thanks varman,
So basically you have added a new field with available before grouping..and filter out the values to consider Approved and rest all to Rejected. Am I right ? ..

Comment: Is it possible to further squeeze the document
Something like below
  {
    "_id" : {
        "test" : 200.0,
        "Approved" : {
            "count" : 2          
            }
        "Rejected" : {
            "count" : 1
            }      
    }
}

Comment: Give me some time. Im out of home.

Comment: @varman..tried with $merge , but breaking the things.. I need to improve my fundamental on mongo for sure .. :D

Comment: how does test come from?

Comment: Able to compare 2 different field, but wanted to compare same field in btn 2 doc.
Ex.
```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "test" : 200.0,
        "status" : "Approved"
    },
    "count" : 3.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "test" : 200.0,
        "status" : "Rejected"
    },
    "count" : 1.0
}
```
Here if test field matches with each other merge the status and count
Like this
  {
    "_id" : {
        "test" : 200.0,
        "Approved" : {
            "count" : 2          
            }
        "Rejected" : {
            "count" : 1
            }      
 }}

Comment: but you dont have anything called `test`

Comment: ahh, you opened a question, You might have posted the link here, that i can understand clearly. Anyhow the answer was given. Goodluck

Comment: I was trying and copy the "test" here as well...still appreciate your answer, it teaches a lot when there is a simplified version..

Comment: you are very welcome. If you have doubts let me know, i will try my best. By the way, try to answer to question. it will help to improve knowledge